# Argument type null is not assignable to parameter type

Tags: c#, generics, null

I'm trying to develop a generic BoundedList class, for which I've created a generic BoundedListNode class. My BoundedList class is as follows:

```
class BoundedList<TE>
{
    private BoundedListNode<TE> _startNode;
    private BoundedListNode<TE> _lastUsedNode;
    protected Dictionary<TE, BoundedListNode<TE>> Pointer;

    public BoundedList(int capacity)
    {
        Pointer = new Dictionary<TE, BoundedListNode<TE>>(capacity);
        _startNode = new BoundedListNode<TE>(null);
        _lastUsedNode = _startNode;
    }
}
```

In the constructor at the _startNode I'm getting the error "Argument type null is not assignable to parameter type TE".

How can I assign null in this case?

Comment: try `class BoundedListNode<TE> where TE: class`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to tell the compiler `TE` is a `class`, meaning a reference type. With an unbounded type, `TE` can also be a value type, which isn't assignable to `null`:

```
public class BoundedListNode<TE> where TE : class
```

Then, you'll be able to assign `null` as an argument in your constructor:

Answer (score 0):

Building upon Yuval's answer, yes indeed the Generic constraint on TE to class, will enable null assignment.

The alternative for assigning a null value, use the `default` keyword when creating a new instance. Consider the simplified example below:

```
void Main()
{
   // p.CustomData will be null, use the default keyword.
   var p = new Person<Car?>(default);
  // p2.CustomData will be the new Car instance
   var p2 = new Person<Car>(new Car("Very fast Skoda"));
}


public class Person<TE>
{   
   public Person(TE customData)=> CustomData = customData;
   public TE CustomData {get;}
}

public record Car(string Name);
```